# How to use Regex pattern in HTML text input

Tags: regex, html, validation

I would like to restrict a text input field in a HTML5 form. I need it only value from 1 to 5

**My code is**

```
 <input type="text" name="count" pattern="[1-5][0-9-.]{1,10}" value="1" required>
```

**Do match (Expectation):**

```
1
1.5
1.584
2
4.68756
5
```

**Don't match (Expectation):**

```
0
.5
0.99
01
05
5.1
6
[a-zA-Z] and other special characters
```

**Now happened (the problem):**

- Not validate non decimal values (1,2,3,4 and 5).
- Validates 5.1 to 5.9

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew .. where is my answer? please read question completely before mark as duplicate

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew now i edit my question

Comment: Try [`pattern="[1-4](?:\.\d+)?|5(?:\.0+)?"`](https://regex101.com/r/aYnU3Q/1)

Comment: Thanks.. its works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="[1-4](?:\.\d+)?|5(?:\.0+)?"
```

It gets parsed as `^(?:[1-4](?:\.\d+)?|5(?:\.0+)?)$` by HTML5 engine. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aYnU3Q/1).

**Details**

- `^(?:` - start of string and start of a non-capturing group
- `[1-4]` - a digit from `1` to `4`
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits (fractional part may contain any number of any digits)
- `|` - or
- `5` - matches `5`
- `(?:\.0+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ zeros (fractional part may contain any number of zeros if the whole part is `5`)
- `)$` - end of the outer "container" group and end of string.

To allow leading zeros, use

```
pattern="0*(?:[1-4](?:\.\d+)?|5(?:\.0+)?)"
         ^^^^^                          ^
```